# How to construct a function to map coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, summation

Surely this question is known by many people but I lack of enough maths knowledge so I prefer ask here.

I have a triangular matrix that represent coefficients, all of them are rational numbers included the zero.

The coefficients come from a summation of a function. I will show the example so you can understand:

$$F(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{n,k}\cdot f(k)$$

where $f(k)$ maybe $b^k$ or $sin(b\cdot k)$ or $k^b$ or any elemental function. In my case it was the falling factorial:

$$F(n)=(b)_n\cdot a_{n,0}+(b)_{n-1}\cdot a_{n,1}+(b)_{n-2}\cdot a_{n,2}+...+(b)_{0}\cdot a_{n,n}$$

So, clarifying my question, exist a tool to construct a generalized function $g(n,k)$ for map coefficients? What Im trying to do is a generalized [antidifference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) of fitting some empiric results, something like an "interpolation" based on the elemental function of $f(k)$, adjust the coefficients on some way so I can construct an $g(n,k)$ that map the coefficients easily

$$F(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}g(n,k)\cdot f(k)$$

If you want to know the matrix of my falling factorial function is

$$a_{n=5} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & & & & \\
  1 & 0 & & & \\
  1 & 1 & -1 & &\\
  1 & 3 & -2 & 2 &\\
  1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow g(n,k)??$$

I hope I was enough clear. This is a very similar (or equal) to the task of data compression.

P.S.: some hints or links on how to make derivatives or integrals/summations from matrix will be appreciated too. Ty.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Your example, I think, you mean to have $F$ and $f$ both be column matrices, and the equation is $F=Af$, where $A$ is your matrix of coefficients? But I don't understand why you call the matrix in your example $a_n$. And your question is confusing, because it sounds like you're saying "How do I construct the function whose values are the entries of the matrix?" and I don't understand what's wrong with the obvious answer $g(n,k) = a_{n,k}$. Are you just asking for recipes for finding, given $F$ and $f$, a useful $A$ satisfying $F = Af$?

Comment: @Hurkyl how to construct some $g(n,k)$ from a matrix of $n*n$? I want a function of the values of _n_ and _k_ that map the matrix.